# How to use Django REST Serializers?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So, after reading the Django REST Framework document, and a bunch of tutorials, I am still having trouble understanding how to use the Django serializers to convert incoming POST (JSON) data into a Python object (sorry, I'm new).

Given that I am posting a JSON string to, say, api/foo/bar, how do I write its serializer?

Example JSON:

```
{ 'name': 'Mr. Foo', address:'Bar Street' }
```

My controller, Foo contains a bar method as follows:

```
@detail_route(
    methods=['post']
)
def bar(self, request, uuid=None):
    serializer = MySampleSerializer(data=request.DATA)

    something.clone(serializer.object)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Can somebody explain to me what should my serializer look like? And how do I access the serialized data from the serializer?

Comment: Are you sure you've read the whole tutorial? I was new too, but I found it extremely well written and useful: it allowed me to add a json-web-api to my apps in no time. Specifically, any reason for not using CBV's? (e.g. ModelViewSet)

Comment: Have you made any Django-model, like the `Snippet` in the tutorial? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/ Like @Pynchia said; the tutorial is very well written and if you follow it fully there should be very little confusion.

Comment: I read it - however I'd like to be able to use the data without a model.

Comment: See here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603027/django-rest-framework-non-model-serializer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you do not want to use a model, you have to create the serializer from scratch. Something like this should maybe work:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length = 100)
    adress = serializers.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

And then you could use it in a request like this:

```
def bar(self, request, uuid=None):
    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    serializer = MySerializer(data = data)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Note however, as you have not created an Django model, you will not be able to save the serialized data (and thus nothing will be saved in the database)

Comment: Thank you!! One more question: once I have the serializer object, how do I access the fields? serializer.data.get() ?

Comment: I do recommend that you use the serializer in conjunction with a Django model object, but yes you can access the data by `name = serializer.data["name"]`

Comment: you might want to use the serializer for the purpose of validation. Therefore, after checking the data is valid, access it via `serializer.validated_data`. Otherwise you might just rest your case with the JSONparser and ignore the serializer.

Comment: You need to amend your answer, `serializers.ModelSerializer` should be  `serializers.Serializer` if you are not using a `model`

Comment: @Incognos My bad! Updated.

Comment: Mhh, i still can't get it to work. My serializer just returns an empty / default string.

Comment: @JB2 Have you looked at the request data to see that you actually get something in the POST?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you pass in the JSON data to the serializer, and then access the data field which will return an ordered dictionary.

```
def bar(self, request, uuid=None):
    serializer = MySampleSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        my_object = serializer.data # Grab the dict of values
```

To define a serializer:

```
class MySampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: good answer. But see OP's recent comment above: "I'd like to be able to use the data without a model."

Comment: Thank you for this concise answer! However yes, as Pynchia said: I would like to be able to use it without a model.

Comment: You cannot get a raw python object out of a serializer. After you pass in data, you can access serializer.data and receive a dictionary. If you want a python object, then a custom create method that creates a python object based off the json representation could be implemented.

Comment: Ok, thanks. However the question remains: how do I associate the JSON fields with my serializer without a model?

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to use the ModelSerializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()
```

and access:

```
serializer = CommentSerializer(data=data)
serializer.is_valid()
# True
serializer.validated_data
```

by the way, all the above is from the DRF [website](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

Comment: You answer is misleading, since the question is specifically about the reception of data via POST (i.e. de-serialization).

Comment: How is it misleading? I distinctly read `how do I write its serializer?` in the question... and he mentions not using a model... He could have easily gotten most of his answer from the docs

Comment: the second half of your answer. You are showing how to serialize. You should show how to de-seralize (and validate) instead

Comment: and instead of making a comment, you downvote? that is how you deserialize

Comment: I am sorry mate, still fighting with SO's constraints. If you edit it, I'll be happy to change it.

Comment: So now it is SO's fault that you feel that it is better to be negative instead of positive? If I refused to change it, I can understand the downvote.