# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) Django rest_framework

Tags: python, django

I am getting an error `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. I'm using rest_framework along with Django.
I'm trying to return all the objects of a model to the frontend. I'm fairly new to Django and can't really understand what's wrong.

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)

During handling of the above exception (0), another exception occurred:
File "C:\Users\sanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\sanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\sanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\sanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\sanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "C:\Users\sanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
File "C:\Users\sanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
raise exc
File "C:\Users\sanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "F:\Project\Project dev\backend\Strix\views.py", line 244, in post
body = json.loads(request.body)
File "C:\Users\sanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Users\sanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\sanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

Exception Type: JSONDecodeError at /sprintlist/
Exception Value: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

code used to return all objects.
views.py

```
class GetSprints(APIView):

def post(self,request):
    body = json.loads(request.body)

    sprints = Sprint.objects.all()

    Sprints=[]

    for sprint in sprints:
        data = {
            "id":sprint.id,
            "name":sprint.name,
            "status":sprint.status,
            "startdate":sprint.startdate,
            "enddate":sprint.enddate
        }
        Sprints.append(data)
    return Response({"Sprints":Sprints},status=200)
```

models.py

```
class Sprint(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    startdate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    enddate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    createdby = models.ForeignKey('User',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    ticketlist = models.ManyToManyField('Ticket',blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: It's currently erroring on the line `body = json.loads(request.body)`. If you have a debugger, you can stop on that line and see what the value is `request.body`. Or you can add the line `print(request.body)` just before the line that breaks. From there you should be able to determine why `request.body` can't be transformed into JSON.

Comment: Cut out the for loop and just pass the query set. Best way would be using a drf serialiser. `class SprintSerializer(serializers.Serializer): name=serializers.CharField().....` and pass that into your response.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328532/how-to-use-django-rest-serializers