# How can I add a non-model/queryset returning view with django-restframework when using DjangoObjectPermissions?

Tags: python, django, api, permissions, django-rest-framework

I have a view that I want to add to my django-restframework api that does not relate to any model. Though I'm using 'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoObjectPermissions' in DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES.

```
class EnumChoices(views.APIView):       
    def get(self, request):
        enums = {}
        return Response(enums)
```

Now Django complains about my view:

```
AssertionError at /api/enums/
Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissions on a view that does not have `.queryset` property or overrides the `.get_queryset()` method.
```

I need the permission class for almost all other views and do not want to get rid of it. How can I get around the mandatory attributes for the one view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a view-specific permission logic to overwrite the model permission check. Create a BasePermission class object and add it to your views permission_classes attribute. Don't forget IsAuthenticated unless you want to allow anonymous users too.

```
class EnumChoices(views.APIView):
    class EnumPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
        def has_permission(self, request, view):
            # whatever permission logic you need, e.g.
            return request.user.has_perm("planning.view_enums")
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, EnumPermission)

    def get(self, request):
        enums = {}
        return Response(enums)
```

Now the view will ensure the user is authenticated and has the view_enums permission.

More info here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions