# TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework

I get a `TypeError` when I try to get data from `MySQL` table and assign it to a `queryset` using following code in Django `ModelViewSet`

```
def queryset(self, request):
      conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', passwd='password123', db='sakila')
      cur = conn.cursor()
      cur.execute("SELECT  city_id, city, country_id FROM city")
      json.dumps(list(cur))

      cur.close()
      conn.close()
```

It gives me following error

> Exception Value:
>   'method' object is not iterable

What am I doing wrong? Any solutions? I'm kind of a noob so if you could explain the solution too, that would be great.

```
Traceback:

  File "C:\Users\Naila Akbar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

> File "C:\Users\Naila Akbar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

> File "C:\Users\Naila Akbar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

> File "C:\Users\Naila Akbar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py" in view
  87.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

> File "C:\Users\Naila Akbar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  466.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

> File "C:\Users\Naila Akbar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  463.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

> File "C:\Users\Naila Akbar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py" in list
  48.         return Response(serializer.data)

> File "C:\Users\Naila Akbar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  674.         ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data

> File "C:\Users\Naila Akbar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  239.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

> File "C:\Users\Naila Akbar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in to_representation
  614.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

> Exception Type: TypeError at /cities/

> Exception Value: 'method' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Please include the **full** traceback of your exception, because it isn't clear where that error is coming from.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't know how to include traceback but I try..

Comment: I don't see where it happens in the code you posted, but since the error is ``'method' object is not iterable`` and you have a method called ``queryset`` and a local var called ``queryset`` I suspect they are getting mixed up somewhere, but I don't see where.  Try changing one of those names and see if it changes anything.

Comment: @nephlm tried..still same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Django REST framework, then you are expected to produce *model instances* (database results) or simple *Python* primitives (built-in types), and it'll take care of serialisation to JSON *for you*. By abstracting away the serialization, the framework can implement content-negotiation, where the client can pick what format they receive the data in. That *could* be JSON, but it could also be something else. I suspect that returning a JSON string is going to upset the assumptions the framework makes.

Return your cursor data in a `rest_framework.response.Response` object instead, do **not** serialize this yourself:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from contextlib import closing

# ...
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', passwd='password123', db='sakila')
with closing(conn), conn as cur:
    with cur:
        cur.execute("SELECT  city_id, city, country_id FROM city")
        return Response(list(cur))
```

From the [*Responses* section in the API Guide](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/):

> REST framework supports HTTP content negotiation by providing a `Response` class which allows you to return content that can be rendered into multiple content types, depending on the client request.
>
> The `Response` class subclasses Django's `SimpleTemplateResponse`. **`Response` objects are initialised with data, which should consist of native Python primitives**. REST framework then uses standard HTTP content negotiation to determine how it should render the final response content.

In the above example I also used [`contextlib.closing()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) to ensure the connection is closed even if there are exceptions in the view, and then used the connection as a context manager to produce the cursor, and then the cursor to ensure it too is closed.

If you do have an an actual model, then use the Django ORM and don't create direct connections yourself. You are using a big, well-integrated machine and are ignoring 95% of that machine here. You won't get connection pooling, transaction management, pagination, etc. etc. etc. Just use proper querysets and model views in that case.

Comment: I'm doing like this
cur.execute("SELECT  city_id, city, country_id FROM city")
 queryset = json.dumps(list(cur))

Comment: @NullPointer: yes, that's correct. Please add the full traceback to your question, because if you still get that error then *your posted code is not the cause*.

Comment: @NullPointer: does your function return anything?

Comment: @NullPointer: also, I see you are using the Django REST framework to handle *this specific function*. The framework won't be able to handle already-serialised data like this.

Comment: yes I'm working on django rest frame work and using ModelViewSet that returns serialize class and queryset to handle data

Comment: @NullPointer: but you don't have a model. You have a list of rows. See [Django REST framework: non-model serializer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13603027) for more info. There a `rest_framework.response.Response` object is returned from the view.

Comment: I know that's api view approach but I want to do it with ModelViewSet. Isn't it poosible?

Comment: Also I've created the model

Comment: @NullPointer: you don't produce models here. Why do you need to use a model view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109880/discussion-between-null-pointer-and-martijn-pieters).

Comment: returning Response(json.dumps(list(cur))) resolved this issue for me