# Django REST Framework - View with serialization without model

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I just recently started developing for Django and am building an API using Django REST Framework and class based views. I am looking for a way to **combine models, sort them based on time and then return a subset of the fields to an API with the table name appended.**

Currently I have the following:

views.py

```
class RunLog(APIView):
        """
        List log for a specific run sorted in reverse chronological order
        """
        def get(self, request, run_id, format=None):
            # Combine and sort based on time (decreasing) 
            result_list = sorted(chain(Output.objects.filter(run=run_id),
                                       Downtime.objects.filter(run=run_id)), 
                                key=attrgetter('start_time'), reverse=True)

            // Replace this with serializer??
            response = Response(serializers.serialize('json', result_list), status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            return response
```

models.py

```
class Output(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    value = models.FloatField()

    run = models.ForeignKey(Run, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Downtime(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    run = models.ForeignKey(Run, blank=True, null=True)
```

I get the following JSON:

```
"[{\"model\": \"app.downtime\", \"pk\": 91, \"fields\": {\"start_time\": \"2016-07-20T14:46:21Z\", \"end_time\": null, \"reason\": \"reason1\", \"run\": 71}}, {\"model\": \"app.downtime\", \"pk\": 101, \"fields\": {\"start_time\": \"2016-07-20T14:46:21Z\", \"end_time\": null, \"reason\": \"reason2\", \"run\": 71}}]"
```

I would like to serialize this data in the following JSON format:

```
    [
        {
            "id": 231,
            "type": "speed",
            "description": "Some description",
            "time": "2016-07-21T21:26:26Z"
        }
    ]

**Where type is the database table and description is concatenated columns from a model.
```

I have looked at the docs and [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603027/django-rest-framework-non-model-serializer) without any luck.

Comment: You can access the DB table name via `ModelObj._meta.db_table`.

Comment: The biggest problem I am having is being able to format the data how I want. 

Being able to take a few fields from a model (using values()) and push those into a new field name, adding more fields (ie tablename via ModelObj._meta.db_table) and then sending that as a response.

Comment: `def your_serializer(obj): return dict(id=obj.id, type="type", ...)`?

Answer (score 0):

As IanAuld suggested in the comments - ModelObj._meta.db_table got the name of the table. I then created a sorted list of dictionaries in views.py:

```
speedList = Speed.objects.filter(run=run_id)
type = Speed._meta.db_table.split('_', 1)[1]
type = type[0].upper() + type[1:]

for speed in speedList:
    description = "Speed change to %.2f (units)" % speed.value
    logList.append({'id':speed.id, 'type':type, 'description':description, 'time':speed.start_time})

# Sort list by decreasing time
resultList= sorted(logList, key=itemgetter('time'), reverse=True)

serializer = LogSerializer(resultist, many=True)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py:

```
class LogSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    type = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = serializers.CharField(max_length=500)
    time = serializers.DateTimeField()
```