# Python Django Rest Post API without storage

Tags: python, json, django, rest, web

I would like to create a web api with Python and the Django Rest framework. The tutorials that I have read so far incorporate models and serializers to process and store data. I was wondering if there's a simpler way to process data that is post-ed to my api and then return a JSON response without storing any data.

Currently, this is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework import routers
from core.views import StudentViewSet, UniversityViewSet, TestViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'students', StudentViewSet)
router.register(r'universities', UniversityViewSet)
router.register(r'other', TestViewSet,"other")

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

and this is my views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import University, Student
from .serializers import UniversitySerializer, StudentSerializer

import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

class StudentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer

class UniversityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = University.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UniversitySerializer

class TestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):    
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({'something': 'my custom JSON'})
```

The first two parts regarding Students and Universities were created after following a tutorial on Django setup. I don't need the functionality that it provides for creating, editing and removing objects. I tried playing around with the TestViewSet which I created.

I am currently stuck trying to receive JSON data that gets posted to the url ending with "other" and processing that JSON before responding with some custom JSON.

**Edit**

These two links were helpful in addition to the solution provided:

[Django REST framework: non-model serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603027/django-rest-framework-non-model-serializer)

http://jsatt.com/blog/abusing-django-rest-framework-part-1-non-model-endpoints/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use their generic [APIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) class (which doesn't have any attachment to Models or Serializers) and then handle the request yourself based on the HTTP request type. For example:

```
class RetrieveMessages(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        posted_data = self.request.data
        city = posted_data['city']
        return_data = [
            {"echo": city}   
        ]
        return Response(status=200, data=return_data)

     def get....
```

Comment: Thank you for the response - APIView turns out to be appropriate for this task!